# Raspberry Pi custom commands in a scripting language through tcp/ip connection

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to control a step motor using a raspberry pi. I finished the motor control part of the raspberry pi, but I am not really sure on how to continue on the tcp/ip connection part of the project.
I am meaning to connect a client through the tcp/ip connection and letting the client upload a code that lets the client control the motor, in which there should already be custom commands implemented (e.g. "clockwise ": turns the motor a number of steps clockwise. "set  1": sets the gpio pin to 1, and etc.)
I apologize because my knowledge in raspberry pi and tcp/ip connections are really limited.

Can someone point me a way in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Are there constraints on only one user at a time? On security/permissions? On client Operating System? On response time? On language?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a scripting solution you can do TCP/IP part using `ssh`. Client can use `ssh` to log into the RPi and run the commands. It can use `scp` for pushing updated code/script.

For automating you can look into [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that lets you script your steps.